# CSS transform on a li forces text in children to 'jump' after scaling in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, css-transforms

I've wrote a simple sticky-notes page. Every note is a list item containing content in paragraph, delete button in span and an image with tooltip. Here`s a piece of HTML containing one note:

```
<ul id="wall" class="ui-sortable">
  <li id="note1">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="del">x</span>
      <p>1221212 23 23 3322 3223</p>
      <img src="..."/>
      <div class="tooltip">Tooltip</div>
    </a>
  </li>
  .
  .
  .
</ul>
```

And here`s the css:

```
ul li a
{
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s ease;
}

ul li a:hover
{
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  font-size: 105%;
  position: relative;
}

ul li p
{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  font-size: 120%;
  font-style: italic;
}

.del
{
  -moz-user-select: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 183px;
  float: right;
  display: none;
  padding: 2px 5px 0 0;
}
```

The issue is, that with this code whole note scales ok, but then after scaling is complete the text (both in p and span) resizes itself a bit (I don't know, about 1-2px) and it looks really bad. Removing -moz-transition from 'ul li a' fixes the issue, but then scaling isn't smooth at all. Has any of you encountered similiar issue? 
I've tried this also:

```
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s ease;
-moz-transition: font-size 0.2s ease;
```

But this doesn't help. Is there any way to use css transformation scale without the 'jumping' text? I'd prefer not to use jQueryUI for now, it's too heavy for using it only for this simple task.

Here`s jsfiddle for this:
[Notes](http://jsfiddle.net/ZzPMf/)

Of course you have to run it from firefox to observe the issue. On chrome it works ok AFAIK.

UPDATE: I've to run it under FF8.0, but I've installed 13.0.1 and this glitch is also visible there.

Comment: try to show your code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Ok, added jsfiddle. Try and run it on firefox.

Comment: did you mean your <p> text is changed and some characters goes to the line below when hover on li?

Comment: No, I mean the slight 'jump' effect on font after the scaling has been complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the font size 105% to 100%.

```
ul li a:hover
  {
    -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 7px black;
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    font-size: 100%;
    position: relative;
  }
```

Comment: You can just omit the font-size entirely (It's 100% anyways).

Comment: It doesn't help. Even removing font-size attribute from hover doesn't help. It still glitches a bit after the scaling. It's a small but really annoing glitch. Like some unnecessary smoothing or enlarging. I don't know what it is.

Comment: @Ziouas it works perfect in my FF13 when omitting the font-size (no breaking). However you can't change the re-calculation|rendering of the font-size after the transition finished. All browsers do that to enhance the readability of the fonts.

Comment: Ok, I didn't mention that I'll have to make it work under firefox 8. From what Christoph worte I understand that in later versions it was changed and I can't override it in 8.0?

Comment: I gave up on whole transform effect, I'm only scaling it now. I don't know where to report that.